# entity_metadata_wrapper - how to remove one item from entity reference field

Tags: entities

I have a entity reference field that holds relations to multiple nodes. I have to remove one item programmatically based on nid. Normally to remove item I've just set it to null like this:

```
$wrapper->field_foobar = NULL;
```

But entity reference is a list, so I have to know delta for element to do something like this:

```
$wrapper->field_foobar[$delta] = NULL;
```

So I have content_id and target_id what should I do to find delta? I know it's possible to do it with simple SQL query, but I gues there should be some way to do that with entity metadata .

Any sugestions?

I'm on Drupal 7 of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) instead, followed by a save:

```
unset($wrapper->field_foobar[$delta]);
$wrapper->save();
```

To find the delta, you can iterate over the collection and look for the node id:

```
foreach($wrapper->field_foobar as $delta => $item)  {
  if ($item->nid->value() == $my_id) {
    unset($wrapper->field_foobar[$delta]);
    $wrapper->save();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it'll be `target_id` for an entity reference field (`$field->target_id->value()`)

Comment: It works! $field->nid->value() is correct. Tyler You saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In summary, when iterating over an entity reference field on a wrapped object, each iteration's object will also be a fully wrapped entity.

Comment: Instead of calling the `unset()` you may use `$wrapper->field_foobar[$delta] = array();`

Comment: Entity metadata wrappers also have the `offsetUnset($delta)` method.  Thus: `$wrapper->field_foobar->offsetUnset($delta);`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function for it, like this:

```
function remove_entity_reference_from_field(&$field, $reference_id){
  $field = array_filter($field, function($value) use ($reference_id) {
    return ($value['target_id'] != $entity_id);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
$node = node_load(98765);
remove_entity_reference_from_field($node->field_foobar[LANGUAGE_NONE], 12345);
node_save($node);
```